# What is the fastest way to read text file from hard drive into memory using Go?

Tags: perl, file, go

I just start using Go after years of using Perl and from initial tests seems like reading text file from a hard drive into hash is not as fast as Perl.

In Perl I use "File::Slurp" module and it helps reading file into memory (into string variable, array, or hash) really fast - in the limits of hard drive Read throughput.

I am not sure what is the best way by using Go to read e.g. 500MB CSV file with 10 columns into memory (into hash) where Key of a Hash is 1st column and Value is rest of 9 columns.

What is the fastest way to achieve this? Goal is to read and store into some Go memory variable as fast as Hard drive can deliver data.

This is one line from input file - there are around 20 million similar lines:

1341,2014-11-01 00:01:23.588,12000,AV7WN259SEH1,1133922,SingleOven/HCP/-PRODUCTION/-23C_30S,0xd8d2a106d44bea07,8665456.006,5456-02,3010-30 N- PHOTO,AV7WN259SEH1

Platform is Win 7 - i7 Intel processor with 16GB Ram. I can install Go on Linux as well if there are benefits in doing so.

Edit:

So one use case that is - load whole file into memory as fast as you can into 1 variable. Later I can scan that variable, split (all in memory) etc.

Another approach is to to store each line as key-value pair during load time (e.g. after X bites are passed or after \N character arrive).

To me - these 2 approaches can yield different performance results. But since I am very new to Golang - it will probably take me days to make best performance algorithm in Golang trying different techniques.

I would like to learn all possible ways to do above in Golang and also recommended ways. At this point I am no concerned about memory usage since this process will be repeated 10,000 times soon as first file processing is finished (each file will be erased from memory soon as processing is done). Files range from 50MB to 500MB. Since there are several thousands of files - any performance gain (even 1 sec gain per file) is significant overall gain.

I do not want to add complexity to the question about what will be done with data later but just want to learn about fastest way to read file from drive and store in hash. I will put more detailed benchmarks on my findings and also as I learn more about different ways to do it in Golang and as I hear more recommendations. I am hoping someone already did research on this topic.

Comment: show at least a few lines of your file?

Comment: File::Slurp is implemented in terms of your system's open(2)/read(2). I imagine Golang's I/O package provides a means of reading an entire file with a minimal number of syscalls and no buffering in a similar manner.

Comment: What platform are you developing this for ? Go provides access to the `syscall.Mmap` function which is a POSIX-compliant way to map a file into memory. This is probably the fastest way to read a file into a `[]byte`. While this does not answer your question, it is a good starting point for you to look further.

Comment: Not much to go on. You could benchmark just parts of the program, try to observe where CPU is going, try a couple approaches to the I/O code. (And, odd thing to say, but it's only 500MB; even a relatively inefficient way to read it shouldn't take *too* long to read that for many apps.)

Comment: SirDarius - can you please post a Go code for reading input.csv file using syscall.Mmap?

Comment: @cikavladimir: if you're reading the file all at once, mmap isn't going to help. This is a pretty simple operation, try it first.

Answer (score 2):

[ioutil.ReadFile](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile) is probably a good first start to read a whole file into memory.  That being said, this sounds like a poor use of memory resources.  The question asserts that File::Slurp is fast, [but this is not general consensus](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=402915) for the particular task you're doing, that is, line-by-line processing.

The claim is that Perl is somehow doing things "fast".  We can look at the [source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/URI/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm) to Perl's `File::Slurp`.  It's not doing any magic, as far as I can tell.  As Slade mentions in comments, it's just using [sysopen](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html) and [sysread](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html), both of which eventually bottom out to plain operating system calls.  Frankly, once you touch disk I/O, you've lost: your only hope is to touch it as few times as possible.

Given that your file is 500MB, and you have to read the all the bytes of the disk file anyway, and you have to a line-oriented pass to process each line, I don't quite see why there's a requirement to do this in two passes.  Why turn this from what's fundamentally a one-pass algorithm into a two-pass algorithm?

Without you showing any other code, we can't really say if what you've done is fast or slow or not.  Without measurement, we can't say anything substantive.  Did you try writing the direct code with [bufio.Scanner()](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) first, and then [measure performance](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs)?